# Goniometry, application of duplication and bisection formulas: question 1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have this exercise n. 160. We know that the $\triangle ABO$ is isosceles and $\beta=2\alpha$ and  only the bisection and duplication formulas should be used.  After $\cos\beta=-\frac 14$. It easy to get $\sin \alpha$. In fact $$\sin \alpha=\sin\frac{\beta}2=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\beta}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}, \quad \cos \gamma=\cos\left(90^\circ -\frac{\beta}2\right)$$
being $\gamma \cong \delta$ and $\gamma+\delta+\beta=180^\circ$ and

$$\gamma =90^\circ-\frac{\beta}2$$
Hence
$$\cos\gamma=\cos\left(90^\circ -\frac{\beta}2\right)=\sin\frac{\beta}2=\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}$$

But the problem is the $\tan \delta$.

$$\tan \delta =\frac{\sin\left(90^\circ-\frac{\beta}2\right)}{\cos\left(90^\circ-\frac{\beta}2\right)}=\frac{\cos\frac{\beta}2}{\sin\frac{\beta}2}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\beta}{2}}}{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{5}.$$

I do not understand how to get the result marked in red with an exclamation point. It is a wrong result from the book. I have another problem with another similar exercise. The tangent does not result. I am waiting for your help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I seem to agree with your calculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion looks correct.

Geometrically if $AO=r$ then $$AB^2=r^2+r^2+\frac{r^2}{2}=\frac{5}{2}r^2 \implies \frac{AB^2}{4}=\frac{5}{8}r^2 \implies \tan \delta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt 5}=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{5}$$